# Re-rendering prop data on button press in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, flux

**UPDATE #2**: I posted the code on JSFiddle for [`LinksScreen`](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanmoran/ycvjL85L/) and [`TimelineDay`](https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanmoran/ycvjL85L/). Sorry I didn't do that earlier!

**UPDATE**: I re-structed my code using the suggestions of . I am now attempting to update `timelineData`, a prop in component `TimelineDay` and re-render `LinksScreen` class. However, nothing happens in my testing. I'm very new to states/props, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Very new to React/JS (*newbie alert*). Let's get into the meaty part of my problem..

Class `LinksScreen` contains flexbox views with props and external components

```
import TimelineDay from '../components/TimelineDay.js';

export default class LinksScreen extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.onPress1 = this.onPress1.bind(this);
    this.onPress2 = this.onPress2.bind(this);
    this.onPress3 = this.onPress3.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        dayOne: [ . . ],
        dayTwo: [. . ],
        dayThree: [. . ],
    }
}
```

Buttons in header have custom `onPressX` functions to update `timelineData` prop with the corresponding `dayOne`, `dayTwo` or `dayThree` data.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.dayBar}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress1}>
                <View>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="numeric-1-box-outline" size={34} color="#FFD344"/>
                     <Text style={styles.day1Text}>Fri, 29th</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
           </View>
```

These are the corresponding button functions that re-assigns child prop `timelineData` with the appropriate arrays

```
onPress1 = () => {
    this.setState({timelineData: this.state.dayOne})
};
onPress2 = () => {
    this.setState({timelineData: this.state.dayTwo})
};
onPress3 = () => {
    this.setState({timelineData: this.state.dayThree})
};
```

I am guessing that, by calling setState(), a re-render is also called. However, this is what I am having difficulty observing in my testing..

This is the method that contains the `TimelineDay` component and `timelineData` prop that I wish to have re-rendered upon button click and prop re-assignment.

```
<View style={styles.eventScheduleView}>
     <TimelineDay ref={(timelineData) => {
         timelineData = this.state.timelineData}}>
     </TimelineDay>
</View>
```

This is probably a very remedial problem, but I (and my university's hackathon leadership team) need the extra clarification.

Feel free to throw out any resources that would be helpful (Flux, states, etc). Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the full code for BOTH components, neatly labeled so everyone knows what they are looking at? Otherwise we are guessing. Also, no clue why you are using refs. I can help more if you reformat code. Instead of breaking the component up into different code sections, just post two snippets, parent component(LinkScreens) and the child component(TimelineDay).

Comment: If you are brand new to React, your mind will also be vaporized to a soup like consistency if you try to use something like Redux.

Comment: Sorry about that! Check out my recent update. I linked the JSFiddles for each @daniel-zuzevich

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state= {
    whatDay: props.string
};
```

You want to set initial state for your component here, not sure what you intend to do with props.string, you can just set it to an empty string.

"Testing action onPress to update prop...", actually you are trying to update state, props cannot be updated using setState.

Taking a little more time to review react fundamentals will be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things here you're doing that are a bit strange. I would venture a guess that your button for whataday2 works.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={{whatDay: "dayOne"}}>
```

and

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={{whatDay: "dayThree"}}>
```

are not doing anything except putting an object into onPress with the property 'whatDay'. However this button passes the actual function you created, that is the proper way to do it.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress}>
```

In addition, there is no need to return setState in your onPress function, each of these touchables are just executing what the onPress button calls. If you. There are two ways to do this properly, the first being to created single onPress calls for each 'whatday' call, like such.

```
onPressTwo = () => {
  this.setState({
     whatDay: "dayTwo"
  });
};

onPressThree = () => {
  this.setState({
     whatDay: "dayThree"
  });
};
....
```

And pass each one to their respective buttons. Alternatively, you could just bind the onPress in each button, and make the onPress take a variable.

```
onPress = (day) => {
  this.setState({
     whatDay: day
  });
};
```

Binding it as such.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress.bind(this, "dayThree"}>
```

You should look into at least applying a Flux or Redux pattern, Flux being easier to pick up with small things. Using one of these patterns will allow for all state to be stored somewhere unlinked to the components, making things much easier to manage.

Comment: After reducing the logic, I established three separate onPress actions:
        this.onPress1 = this.onPress1.bind(this);
        this.onPress2 = this.onPress2.bind(this);
        this.onPress3 = this.onPress3.bind(this);

Each 'onPress' function would attempt to set `Timeline` `timelineData` child prop with the appropriate array (defined in parent this.state):
           this.state = {
             dayTwo: [ ..],
             dayThree: [ .. ],
          }
Then set the `timelineData` prop:
        onPress1 = () => {
        this.setState({timelineData: this.state.dayOne})

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted comment, still getting used to StackOverflow. I edited my original post to include your architecture suggestions. If you have time I'd love to have you review it. Thanks!

Comment: You passed timelineData to ref, the purpose of that property is only to reference that component, not pass it data. Set state does indeed cause a re-render, but nothing will change if the data is not placed in somewhere visible. It's also a better bet to put your data on 'this' rather than state, and only update state from this. State should be reserved for what only causes a visible change. Normally, flux or redux would solve this problem.